# when I press the play button I want to play last unlocked level Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, playback

When I open my game I want to press the play button and then play the last level that I've played before I closed my game.

Comment: Save the last level then load it next time. It would be good to add code and mention where you are stuck in your next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you load a level, you could use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to save the name of that scene. Upon loading the game the next time, you can use the [LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) function of SceneManager to load the scene whose name we stored in PlayerPrefs.